# Slot content of template into my inline component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have this template:

```
<template>
 <my-body-component inline-component>
    <slot/>
 </my-body-component>
</template>
```

and I want  my-body-component to be an inline component which contains whatever is in the slot, however when I render the body this way:

```
const my-body-component= {
  render(h) {
    return this.$slots.default;
  }
};
```

I can't seem to access this.$slots.default.
What would be a good way to get the slot content inside my own inline component?

I also get: "'render' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions." this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Vue.extend({})` to have types inference.

Returning `this.$slots.default` is fine as long as the slot contains a single element (because Vue 2 can't render multiple fragments).

```
const myBodyComponent = Vue.extend({
  render(h) {
    return this.$slots.default
      ? this.$slots.default.find(vnode => vnode.tag)!
      : h('span')
  }
})
```

If it can happen the slot contains multiple elements, instead:

```
return h('div', this.$slots.default)
```